# Windows 7 can't see Ubuntu shared folders and I can't find credentials for Ubuntu file on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have 3 PC's. On two of them I'm running Windows 7 professional and one Linux Ubuntu as media storage server. With desktop machine I have problem deleting credentials of Ubuntu server and they are still remembered after typing in cmd:

`net use * /delete`

After that I rebooted PC, and I was still able to enter shared folder without any prompt for credentials. I have been looking into the credential manager in windows 7 and there was nothing stored.

So how do I delete credentials without reinstalling OS?

Second problem is about network discovery.

My desktop PC can see all shared folders on my home network and access them, as well Ubuntu server is visible on the network when I'm using Desktop PC. But when I'm using my laptop I can only see Desktop PC. And most of the time I'm unable to access files on Ubuntu server. Once in a while I can access Ubuntu server by typing `\\ubuntuserver`, but that is one in 100 tries.

I'm confused now, Desktop (Win7) and server(Ubuntu) are working together without any problems, but when I connect Laptop (Win7) to home wi-fi, same network, I have mentioned problem above.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting credentials should be work like this:

```
net session \\ubuntuserver /delete
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/326285/391060

Comment: I did that several times, and all other options that I know and that I found on internet. After typing just net session I have this line `There are no entries in the list.` After that I try to log in on server to view shared folders and I just cant. So I might assume that the problem is in correct settings of the Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Do you get an error message on Windows? Have you checked the logs on the Windows machine (win+r -> eventvwr.msc)? Have you tested to connect to the IP address instead of name "ubuntuserver"?

Comment: I was not able to connect to with the IP, it was giving me the same result. First the Windows machine reported problem with the permissions on the Linux machine, both the name and IP. Second was path to the server, to check if I wrote correctly name and password. When it was set on Linux to quest account can do read/write all access was fine. But I don't want to set to guest account, I want to set different folders for different users. Will dig for more.

Comment: I assume the problem on the side of ubuntuserver. Perhaps this question will help you: https://askubuntu.com/q/102924/733411